# (OpenCV) put date in filename

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, filenames

I want to save VideoCapture in some condition,
so I wrote following code:

```
  date = datetime.now()
  detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector() 
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)    #I use second camera
  global count, no_face
  total_number = 0
  count = 0
  no_face = 0
  num_bad_posture = 0
  not_detected_posture = 0
  while True:

        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame = cv2.resize(frame,None,fx=sf,fy=sf, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        dets = detector(gray,1) 

        if not dets:
              print('no face')
              no_face += 1
              if no_face > 15:
                    print('no face!! for real!!')
                    now = str(date.now())
                    not_detected = cv2.resize(frame,None,fx=5,fy=5,interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
                    not_detected_posture += 1
                    print(type(now))
                    cv2.imwrite('./images/non_detected/non_detected({0},{1}).jpg'. format(not_detected_posture,now),not_detected)
                    no_face=0
        for i, d in enumerate(dets):
              no_face = 0
              w = d.width()
              h = d.height()
              x = d.left()
              y = d.top()
```

If I run this code, the file is not saved.
Also if I delete `date.now()` and just put `num_detected`, it is saved properly
I have no idea what is wrong with the file name(because it's type is `str` and other `str`s are saved properly.

Also if I do

```
 print(type(now),now)
```

[image]
it appears

I need help.

Comment: thank you editing the contents! I didn't know how it works...
I should've study more.. sorry about that

Comment: The arguments you are passing to the `.format` method are incorrect / extra in number. The `{0}` in the string represent the *first* argument passed to `format`, which in your case is `date.now()`. And you are passing three arguments but only consuming 2 (`{0}`, `{1}`).

Comment: I have changed the code and edited it again.
so for {0} it's 'not_detected_posture'
and for {1} it's 'str(date.now())'
and still I don't know whats going on

Comment: We need some more code to work with it. Especially the part where you import / declare `date`. Because in the current code, there's nothing specifically wrong that will cause the problem.

Comment: with out date time the files are saved properly like'non_detected(1).jpg'. However if I add 'str(date.now())' the file is not saved. (I've also checked type(str(date.now())) and it's type is <str>

Comment: I edited the half-whole code

Comment: As per the current thing, I suspect no reason for the code to do that. If it's working without the `date.now()`, then it should work with it too.

Comment: yeah... it clearly state that it is a 'str' and when I put other 'str' it saves well...   I am suffering

Comment: Try giving a hard-coded string in place of `now`, e.g. `'123'`. See if that works.

Comment: "non_detected(1,123).jpg" is saved. so it works porperly

Comment: Now try hard-coding the date first, then the datetime.

Comment: so you mean   .jpg'. format(str(date))?? that doesn't work also

Comment: No, I mean try `'2017-08-19'` in place of the `'123'` that you just tried. And then try with `'2017-08-19 17:42:30.123456'`

Comment: as I think about it is is because in date string there is a "." inside it???

Comment: oh ok I will try

Comment: oh man you are right!! so 2018-08-19 does work and 2017-08-19 17:42:30.123456 does not work!! I really really appreciate your advise!!

Comment: The problem could be with the `':'` or the `'.'`, I am not sure which one, because you can have filenames that include those and you can write such filenames from within python AFAIK. So, it might be an issue specific to `cv2`

Comment: one big lesson from you thanks a lot!

Comment: What OS is this on?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a more limited set of characters for the filenames, avoiding things like spaces, colons, parentheses. Use a custom datetime format to generate a timestamp in a form you want.

Example:

```
from datetime import datetime
from os import path


BASE_DIR = './images/non_detected'
PREFIX = 'non_detected'
EXTENSION = 'jpg'
file_name_format = "{:s}-{:d}-{:%Y%m%d_%H%M%S}.{:s}"


date = datetime.now()
not_detected_posture = 0


file_name = file_name_format.format(PREFIX, not_detected_posture, date, EXTENSION)

file_path = path.normpath(path.join(BASE_DIR, file_name))

# ---------

print("File name = '%s'" % file_name)
print("File path = '%s'" % file_path)
```

Output:

```
File name = 'non_detected-0-20170819_152459.jpg'
File path = 'images/non_detected/non_detected-0-20170819_152459.jpg'
```

Simple, unambiguous and portable.

---

Perhaps one more improvement. If you have a rough idea how many images you will generate, you can zero-pad the number, so that the filenames are sorted in order. For example, if you know there will be at most 10000, then you can do

```
file_name_format = "{:s}-{:04d}-{:%Y%m%d_%H%M%S}.{:s}"
```

to you get a file name like

```
File name = 'non_detected-0000-20170819_152459.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be with the `':'` or the `'.'` in the filename due to the inclusion of the datetime. I am not sure which one, because you can have filenames that include those and you can write such filenames from within python AFAIK. So, it might be an issue specific to `cv2`.